# Heisenberg Hamiltonian matrix and subspaces

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

I'm dealing with a 4-site Heisenberg's model with no external field:

$$
\begin{align*}
H = \sum_{i<j=0}^3h_{ij}, \quad where\ h_{ij} \equiv J_{ij}(\vec{\sigma_i}\cdot\vec{\sigma_j}) = J_{ij}(X_i\otimes X_j+Y_i\otimes Y_j+Z_i\otimes Z_j)
\end{align*}
$$

The total Hamiltonian matrix could be represented by a 16 by 16 matrix. However, if there's only one particle spin up, can I use a 4 by 4 matrix to represent the total Hamiltonian? If there are 2 particles spin up, how can I use a 6 by 6 matrix to represent H_total, instead of writing down the 16 by 16 matrix?

Also, can I say that the total Hilbert space could be decomposed into a set of orthogonal subspaces each of which corresponds to a value of total spin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Ising case (only ZZ terms) you could but now you have to be more careful because you have the XX and YY terms in the Hamiltonian (isotropic Heisenberg model). Take for example the state $| \uparrow \downarrow \downarrow \downarrow \rangle$ which by your conjecture should be in the $4 \times 4$ block of the Hamiltonian. The XX term mixes this state with $| \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow \downarrow \rangle$, which is outside your  $4 \times 4$.
The correct thing to do is to divide the Hilbert space into blocks of different *total* spin. As a simpler example consider the two-site case. There you find the famous decomposition $\frac{1}{2} \otimes \frac{1}{2} = 1 \oplus 0$ where $1$ is the 3-dimensional triplet sector and $0$ is the 1-dimensional singlet. With 4 sites you get something even more complicated.